# F#: How to add event handler in an inherited type

Tags: inheritance, f#, event-handling

I have a base class with an event and an inherited class, where I would like to add a handler, e.g.

```
type BaseClass() =
    let event = new Event<unit>()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member t.MyEvent = event.Publish


type Inherited() =
    inherit BaseClass()

    do  base.MyEvent.Add(fun () -> ())
```

However I get an error on the final line:
`FS0419 'base' values may only be used to make direct calls to the base implementations of overridden members`.

One approach I've tried is using the `this`  instead:

```
type Inherited() as this =
    inherit BaseClass()

    do  this.MyEvent.Add(fun () -> ())
```

This does work, however I was wondering if there is a more appropriate solution using an `override` suggested in the error message?

As I thought there must be a good reason why `base.MyEvent.Add...` is disallowed - but I don't know the syntax that's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is hidden in subtle implementation details, which are elaborated on by Don Syme in this post:

https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/9806#issuecomment-679264925

"The workaround is to use add_Event":

```ml
    do  base.add_Event (fun _ _ -> ())
```

Comment: Thank you, it does look like this ultimately compiles to what I would expect to see if written in the constructor using C# with `base.Event += ...`

Answer (score 1):

I think the short answer is no. Using `this` is correct in your example. The need for `base` arises only when you're overriding a member and want to call the base implementation from the derived type, which isn't the case here.

However, you can make an abstract event like this:

```ml
[<AbstractClass>]
type BaseClass() =
    let event = new Event<unit>()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    abstract member MyEvent : IEvent<unit>
    default _.MyEvent = event.Publish
```

And then reference it via `base` like this:

```ml
type Inherited() =
    inherit BaseClass()

    do base.MyEvent.Add(fun () -> ())

    let otherEvent = new Event<unit>()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    override _.MyEvent = otherEvent.Publish
```

Comment: It creates 2 stores for event handler, one in base class, one in derived. As result subscription may work unexpectedly. Example https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNALiBOBXAdgHwNoB4CCAjCM8AhgMYwDCwREEAfALoCwAUDAJ4AOApgAQBC1LpWoQAFAEoeAXhY85PYFxg8uANy7JlUnsi4B3HgFF1mzCgCWMWhJaz5WcgBkAksY1WmzeTyL5CpZQBbLkDcLngeAFk2N00eEB5XExgzZEtaOzkAEy4wIkRgZQB9ADpo2K0VZJKABURcYHMIAAtMnhZ2bkTkZvDLLiyJaTbzHr7lAQghKhobL3lFZQB7GF74CukdfSNk1PS5tqyl9vnvOVxBMpjq7CzBsBQeIYBaWh4OeFGYMGQeACILlM/uI2t4VmsKrV6o0WiVbvdHi83h8vj9/jlPuossDbKceA4XBUGG0lup4J8cjxSuVkptweFIXUGk1Wni2sFQuEqSUAEpNLgVIbaenraoAFU+AHNJeEDsxnGNPjABhJefzBeIgA

Comment: It's certainly unusual, but I think that's the expected behavior of my example. The derived class's event is the only one that's visible to external callers.

Comment: Thank you, just to clarify slightly, in this case the `base` class comes from a library, so I can't change the definition there, however I'm looking to add a handler during construction of the inheriting class - if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use Composition over Inheritance.

```
type Base() =
    let event = new Event<unit>()

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member _.MyEvent = event.Publish

type Composition() =
    let b = Base()
    do b.MyEvent.Add(fun _ -> printfn "Called!")

    member _.Base = b
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, for this specific case I want to keep the inheritance, however good to know as an alternative